# Tell yum update to given date, no later

Tags: linux, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to tell yum to update to a certain date's patches.

For instance, let's say a test box gets updated last Thursday. The owner beats on the machine and determines the patch set is good, so I want to update the production box with last Thursday's patches, not today's (the newer ones haven't been tested).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: well, the common practice is to have two repositories - testing and release. And you move package into release when testing is done.

Comment: Sounds like a job for satellite/spacewalk to me ...